# C - Replace $$ in string with ID from getpid()?

Tags: c, string, replace

If I have a string like the following:

```
char* exampleString = "test$$";
```

Let's say that `getpid()` returns `1587`.

How can I replace the `$$` in the string with the result of `getpid()` such that the result would be a string `"test1587"`?

Comment: I have to be able to replace $$ where ever it exists in the string. The string could be "dfkgdfkgd$$fds" and I would need to replace it in the middle of the string. Any ideas?

Comment: Using literal strings you can't, since they are *read-only* in C. You need to use array, long enough to fit the modifications you do to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `"test$$"` is immutable and a pointer to it should better be `char const*` instead of `char*` you'd have to copy it to an array where you then can replace `"$$"`.

Possible solution:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char const *input = "foo$$bar";
    pid_t pid = 1234;

    size_t format_length = strlen(input);
    char *format = calloc(format_length + 2, 1);
    if (!format) {
        fputs("Couldn't allocate memory :(\n\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // copy input to format replacing "$$" with "%ld" in the process
    bool replacement_done = false;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < format_length + replacement_done; ++i) {
        if (!replacement_done && i + 1 < format_length &&
            input[i] == '$' && input[i + 1] == '$')
        {
            format[  i] = '%';  // just
            format[++i] = 'l';  // being
            format[++i] = 'd';  // safe.
            replacement_done = true;
            continue;
        }

        format[i] = input[i - replacement_done];
    }

    if (!replacement_done) {
        free(format);
        fputs("Nothing to do :(\n\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char *result = malloc(1);
    if (!result) {
        free(format);
        fputs("Couldn't allocate memory :(\n\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // there is no guesswork needed, snprintf() will tell the needed size
    int bytes_needed = snprintf(result, 1, format, (long)getpid());
    if (bytes_needed < 0) {
        free(format);
        free(result);
        fputs("snprintf() failed :(\n\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char *temp = realloc(result, ++bytes_needed);
    if (!temp) {
        free(format);
        free(result);
        fputs("Couldn't allocate memory :(\n\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    result = temp;

    int written = snprintf(result, bytes_needed, format, (long)getpid());  // long should be big enough
    if(written < 0 || written >= bytes_needed ) {
        free(format);
        free(result);
        fputs("snprintf() failed :(\n\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    puts(result); // done.

    free(format);
    free(result);
}
```

Comment: What would the code for this look like? And would it be possible to convert this array back into a char*?

Comment: @yoyo1 Arrays naturally decays to pointers to its first element. If you have a `char` array then the decayed pointer type will be `char *`.

Comment: @yoyo1 "What would the code for this look like?" I'm thinking about that. Can there be multiple "$$"?

Comment: @Swordfish Let's assume there is only one instance of "$$" per char* string

Comment: Sorry @Swordfish I had marked an accepted answer right before you posted this.. I'd still like to thank you though because you did help me understand this concept more! Thanks!

Comment: @yoyo1 just keep in mind that the accepted code doesn't check for errors on memory allocation, won't work correctly if the size of `pid_t` is bigger than `int`, doesn't clean up memory.

Comment: @Swordfish Yes I've changed a few things about it. I also didn't know I could change the accepted answer, so I switched it to you. Thanks for the help once again.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a direct substitution because your string (character array) is not long enough to hold the pid, and of course, if declared as a string literal is also not mutable.

There are a couple of ways you could go with this, but here's a reasonably elegant one:

```
/* Modify the existing string to be a pattern string for snprintf */
int len = strlen(exampleString) - 1; /* Can you see why I might do this? */
char* formatString = strdup(exampleString); /* Because we can't modify a literal */
int newLen = len + 12; /* How about this? */
char *pidString = malloc(newLen);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (formatString[i] == '$' && formatString[i+1] == '$') {
    formatString[i] = '%';
    formatString[i+1] = 'd';
    break;
  }
}
snprintf(pidString, newLen - 1, formatString, getpid());
```

Can you follow how this works?

How would you enhance this to fail gracefully if the exampleString does not contain $$ ?

Comment: Why did other guys say char* is immutable, but then you modify it by doing exampleString[i] = ?

Comment: I was wrong in my first try. They were right. I fixed it.

Comment: But isn't that same thing? "char* formatString" that is still char* type, which I thought we can't modify

Comment: "`/* Can you see why I might do this? */`" unless you do it for obfuscation, you do it in the wrong place.

Comment: @yoyo1 Strings like "foobarbaz" cannot be directly modified unless they are copied to an array or dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: Would you do it in the loop, @Swordfish? I try to keep arithmatic out of my loops.

Comment: Swordfish can you post example code of how you would do this please?

Comment: `for (i = 0; i + 1 < len; ++i)` with `len` holding the value its name suggests.

Comment: Or you could rename `len` to `leaveRoomForTheSecondDollarSignLen`

Comment: `snprintf(pidString, newLen - 1, exampleString, getpid());` no need for `-1`.

Comment: Okay I implemented this functionality and it appears to work for me. Thanks!